# Basic WordPress Loop - Pagination?

Tags: php, wordpress

So have I missed something? because if I do the following - in `single.php` while the database contains 4 posts:

```
if(have_posts()){
    while(have_posts()){
        the_post();
        // post content here
    }

    var_dump(get_next_posts_link('asdasdsad')); die();
}
```

I get null. Which seems really wrong. This is just your basic old loop ..... there are 4 other posts in the database ... so did I fail at something? I know this function has to be used in the loop.

help?

Comment: The code you have posted above will only fetch the single post. Because `single.php` only contain single post data.

Comment: Ya but you can still do single based navigation where it goes one post to the next or one post to the previous. Am I using the wrong function? to get the next post? to allow a user to go to the next post?

Comment: Are you linking to a older or newer post?

Comment: How much posts do you have on that page? Do the all 4 posts persists on that page? If there are no more posts (no matter back or forward) it will return nothing. The page size is the important point here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way was to do as I was doing but inside the if statement I needed to use `next_post_link` and `previous_post_link` respectively. as these let me move between the next and previous post.

Comment: You mean inside de while loop not the if, the first line of my answer say: "Your function is not called inside the loop."

Comment: No its out side the while loop and inside the if statement.

Answer (score 0):

Your function is not called inside the loop.

Try this:

```
   <?php
// set the "paged" parameter (use 'page' if the query is on a static front page)
$paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;

// the query
$the_query = new WP_Query( 'cat=1&paged=' . $paged ); 
?>

<?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : ?>

<?php
// the loop
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); 
?>
<?php the_title(); ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>

<?php

// get_next_posts_link() usage with max_num_pages
echo get_next_posts_link( 'Older Entries', $the_query->max_num_pages );
echo get_previous_posts_link( 'Newer Entries' );
?>

<?php 
// clean up after our query
wp_reset_postdata(); 
?>

<?php else:  ?>
<p><?php _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' ); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: I edited my answer try now reference: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_next_posts_link

Comment: This seems retardedly complicated just to get pagination workin on single.php to go back and forth between previous and next posts.

Comment: If 20 lines of code is retardedly complicated I do not know, but that is extracted from official documentation

Comment: Also your query is for category one, meaning ou want all posts in category one - I ant all posts in general regardless of category .

Comment: Just remove 'cat=1' from new WP_Query( 'cat=1&paged=' . $paged );  and that's all